# email function not passing variable to view

Tags: php, laravel

i want to pass a variable $data to my email views but i get undefined variable. 
this is the controller method

```
public function broadcastemail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,
        [
            'subject' => 'required',
            'emailMessage' => 'required'
        ]);

     $emailMessage = $request->emailMessage;

      $data['emailMessage'] = $emailMessage;

     Mail::send('backend.user.emailMessage', $data, function($message)
    {
        $subject = request()->subject;
        $user = User::find('31');
        $email = $user->email;
        $name = $user->first_name;
        $message->to($email, $name)->subject($subject)->with('data',$data);
    });
     //Mail::to($to)->send($data);
     //send_email($to, $name, $subject, $message);


    return back()->withSuccess('Mail Sent Successfuly');
}
```

and this is my view

```
<p>{{$data['emailMessage']}}</p>
```

Comment: Try just `<p>{{ $emailMessage }}</p>`

Comment: yes that worked thanks, i actually didn't notice that error

Answer (score 0):

try to use {{ $emailMessage }} instead of {{$data['emailMessage']}} in your view and **use** keyword for using inside the **closure function of  MAIL**

Comment: or to pass array then try like this Mail::send('backend.user.emailMessage', ['data'=>$data], function($message) use($data)